# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "camAllocateImage" referenced by "libjni_part.so"

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I want to run an Android application using ndk with OpenCV and Camellia library.
The compilation is done successfully but after runnig the app it crashs with this log :

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "camAllocateImage" referenced by "libjni_part.so"...
```

My Android.mk file is :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

include /Path/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES +=  /Path/camellia

LOCAL_MODULE    := jni_part
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := jni_part.cpp
LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS := true

LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -llog -ldl -landroid

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Please how to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

From your Android.mk, you are linking with a dynamic version of OpenCV. A solution would be to link OpenCV and the other library statically on your dynamic library. It will increase size but it won't require the user to install OpenCV by themselves, which is ugly IMHO.

Just add

```
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC
```

before the line including the OpenCV.mk. I haven't worked with the other library, but linking with the .a files should make it work too.

Comment: Thanks for you response, but this doesn't fix the problem !

Comment: The error in particular looked like for a Camellia method. Did you link it statically too? If you do ldd on your .so library (or readelf -d), does it still list any library that is not from the system?